# Dynamic titles in Action bar

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-actionbar

I have a MainActivity with an Action bar (App title, Search icon) and a simple RecyclerView (list of items from a string array) + onClickListener.

When a user clicks on one of the items in the RecyclerView, a new activity is opened.

Now, I want that the title in the Action bar in the new activity shows the the title of the item that was clicked in the RecyclerView. Dynamically. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass text in the intent and in onCreate method you need to get text i.e sent via intent and set that text in the toolbar title text as below -

```
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```